# How to create tab-able content in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabControl` in my WPF application. I want my application to basically support multiple "instances" within the single program. For example, think about web browsers, they allow you to have multiple instances of websites in different tabs, I want to achieve similar functionality where my application contains several instances of "sub applications".

The problem I currently face is that I have to copy-paste the same XAML to every tab, because each tab has exactly the same markup and UI, but different data. Another problem is that I need functionality to dynamically create those tabs.

Here's a screenshot of my application at its current state. As you can see, there are 2 tabs on the top and the second has transparent background since it's inactive.

[image]

So, how do I create a tab-able system where the UI of the tab remains the same for every tab and I only need to develop with one XAML UI and duplicate that for each tab?

Requirements:

- Every tab has the same UI.
- Every tab has different data for the UI elements.
- As a developer I want to work on the tab's XAML only once and right within Visual Studio.

Ideally I would love a plain simple sample project/code where there is one unstyled tab control and the application upon startup dynamically creates 2-n tabs which all have the same UI, but with different data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in another answer there are probably lots of ways to do this, but here's my simple way:

Define a DataTemplate that defines the content of each your identical tabs.  The controls in the data template will bind to the view model of the currently selected tab.  I've put a single TextBlock in my example but you can easily extend this.

using this Xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <Samples:TabBindingViewModels />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" 
                      DataType="{x:Type Samples:TabBindingViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"  
                DisplayMemberPath="Header" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Grid>
```

and this view model code:

```
public class TabBindingViewModels
{
    public TabBindingViewModels()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TabBindingViewModel>
                    {
                        new TabBindingViewModel(1),
                        new TabBindingViewModel(2),
                        new TabBindingViewModel(3),
                    };
    }

    public IEnumerable<TabBindingViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class TabBindingViewModel
{
    public TabBindingViewModel() : this(0)
    {
    }

    public TabBindingViewModel(int n)
    {
        Header = "I'm the header: " + n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Content = "I'm the content: " + n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

we get:

[image]

I quite like this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out) on styling the tab control.  You can easily put more complex content into the tab headers as well as the content.

You should examine the full template of the tab control to gain an insight into how it works.  Use Blend or VS11 beta to extract the template.

In order to dynamically add/delete tabs, now all you need to do is add/delete items to the ObservableCollection of view models.

Answer (score 2):

This could actually turn into a rather large answer because there are many different paths you could take.

It's important to understand that a TabControl is an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), which means it can contain a collection of objects, such as UserControls that make up each module. As such, you could start by binding the Items property to an [ObservableCollection{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of some UserControl objects that live inside of some module project that implements an interface like [IModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.modularity.imodule.aspx) from Prism. The interface defines the starting point of any module that can be loaded within a tab. As modules are requested, you would simply load the assembly and add a tab that contains a reference to the a region defined in the module.

It's actually not very difficult, but I'd recommend you read up on [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) because it will handle a lot of the heavy lifting for you. I've recently gone through building an interface exactly like the one you describe using Prism.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't even known about Prism.

Comment: Are there some sample demo applications I could take a look?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any and my application isn't open source. The quick start guides here might help you get started. If you get stuck, feel free to ask a new question. ;-) I promise it's not too hard once you get into it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921153(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec15

Comment: with your past expertise, could you perhaps write a simple application with one tab control that gets 2+ tab items created during app launch all with the same UI but with different data? I'm sure I'm not the only way looking into this and that sample code/project would benefit many.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Caliburn.Micro for an `MVVM` framework-based solution. The exact question you're asking is solved in one of the sample solutions.

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does it have some requirements? I tried opening many of the samples in VS 2011 and most of them complained about missing assemblies and I even fixed some of them by manually adding ones I found from Silverlight bin folder, but it still complains e.g. `The property 'Dock' does not exist on the type 'StackPanel' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'`. Do you remember which sample exactly answers my question --- then I can keep trying to fix that particular sample :)

Comment: @rFactor, the name of the sample was Caliburn.Micro.SimpleMDI. It one of the few non-Silverlight projects in the samples list. I still have VS 2010, and it loads and runs fine on it.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't unblocked the zip file before unzipping. Right click the zip and select properties.  Hit the 'unblock' button.  Now unzip it.  You'll probably find things build a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, my approach would be to startup a MVVM provider inside of a ApplicationDomain for each instance or tab. When you kill/close the tab, unload the app domain.