# Update TabItemHeader when TabItem content changes

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, tabcontrol

My WPF application has a TabControl with 4 TabItem's. 
Each TabItem has a different ListView with GridView as View.
The ItemContainerStyle of the TabControl define a custom Header with the 'normal' ContentPresenter and a TextBox.

How can I update the TextBox of each TabItem header to show the number of items of each LisView when ListView.ItemSource changes? The ItemSource is periodically set asynchronously from a thread in code behind.

`RunOnUI(() =>
{
    firstTabList.ItemsSource = itemsFirstList;
});`

Thanks

Comment: How do you set ItemsSource? What is your approach - MVVM or simple event handlers in code-behind?

Comment: I just answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547461/how-to-create-tab-able-content-in-wpf-c/9648672#9648672.  That may help.  If not, post some code.

Comment: @EvAlex: I'm using code-behind.

Comment: @Phil: That's a nice solution. Thanks for the guideline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using code behind then you can name your *TabItem*

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabItem1" ...>
```

and then set the header when you update the ItemsSource

```
RunOnUI(()=>{
    firstTabList.ItemsSource = itemsFirstList;
    tabItem1.Header = string.Format("Header: {0}", itemsFirstList.Count);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. In another context, is it possible to do via XAML binding, with a Converter receiving the list and returning the number of items?

Comment: You don't need a converter, you need a view model with INotifyPropertyChanged support.  You could easily adapt the example I pointed you to.