# Set the SelectedTab in ViewModel in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two tabs with grids. The grids are the same in each of the tab. When the user open a file I want the contents of the file go to the selected tab only. How do I set the binding for the selected tab? I'm thinking I can use the same view model. If the viewmodel SelectedTab is the same as the tab selection then the data will go on that tab.

This is my view

```
<TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <TabItem Header="One">
        <views:ShowView x:Name="OneView" MaxWidth="1000"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Two">
        <views:ShowView x:Name="TwoView" MaxWidth="1000"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In my ViewModel I have

```
private int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
```

This is always never set. How do I get OneView and TwoView to know what the value of SelectedIndex is?

Comment: That's hurt me to see View or UI related in ViewModel ... That's not MVVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this answer [How to create tab-able content in WPF/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547461/how-to-create-tab-able-content-in-wpf-c)

In ResourceDictionary

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel}">
        <view:View />
 </DataTemplate>
```

In xaml

```
<TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" 
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

In MainWindowViewModel

```
  Items = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>
                {
                    new View(0),
                    new View(1),
                    new View(2)
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `SelectedIndex` property in your ViewModel is a number?

You can't bind a `TabControl` *item* (`TabItem` content) to an *index*, but TabControl also has a `SelectedIndex` property, so you can probably just change your binding to this:

```
<TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    ...
```

Comment: That gives me the SelectedIndex for the MainWindow, but how do I pass that info to OneView and TwoView. It is always zero because it is not set and default to zero.

Comment: I edited the question with your SelectedIndex change.

Comment: kay00 - whenever you select the first `TabItem` (click on tab on the top) - you will see the whatever `<view:ShowView x:name=OneView...` represent. When you click on second tab (with header "Two") the next view-model (?) will be shown. `SelectedIndex` is the property of `TabControl`.